# R max value of column where different column equals specific value

Tags: r, max

I'm looking for a way to find the maximum value of a column, but only in rows where a different column equals a given value.

Comment: To explain the downvotes: You could found the answer easily by reading an introduction to the language. Please do some research before asking a question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! People are generally much more happy to help if you provide a [**minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) together with the **code you have tried**. Also have a look at [a nice **checklist for questions** on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose all your data is stored in a data frame called dat

```
max(dat$columnYouWantMaxOf[dat$columnYouWantToHaveSpecificValue==ValueYouWantThisColumnToHave])
```